# how to make half round rect in BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

[image]

Below email, user will enter email n below password a user will enter password, i m able to make square but upper square should be curve in upper side and lower square in lower side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something I made that I think will do what you want. You just have to add them to this Manager. Note that I don't think I have it compensating for things like margin or padding, so you can either figure that in with the `paint()` method, or just enclose it in another Manager that has the proper padding/margin:

```
public class GroupFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
    private int _rounding;
    private int _bgColor;
    private int _borderColor;

    private boolean _divider;
    private int _dividerColor;

    public GroupFieldManager(boolean divider, long style) {
        super(style);
        _rounding = 20;
        _bgColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        _borderColor = 0xAAAAAA;
        _divider = divider;
        _dividerColor = 0xAAAAAA;
    }

    public GroupFieldManager(boolean divider) {
        this(divider, 0);
    }

    public GroupFieldManager() {
        this(false, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Sets whether or not to draw a divider
     * @param on
     */
    public void setDivider(boolean on) {
        _divider = on;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the color for the divider (also turns divider on)
     * @param color
     */
    public void setDividerColor(int color){
        _dividerColor = color;
        _divider = true;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the background color for the grouping
     * @param color
     */
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        _bgColor = color;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the border color for the grouping
     * @param color
     */
    public void setBorderColor(int color) {
        _borderColor = color;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the amount of rounding for the border
     * @param rounding
     */
    public void setRounding(int rounding) {
        _rounding = rounding;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        int oldColor = graphics.getColor();

        //draw the background
        graphics.setColor(_bgColor);
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), _rounding, _rounding);

        //draw the border
        graphics.setColor(_borderColor);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), _rounding, _rounding);

        //draw dividers
        if(_divider) {
            graphics.setColor(_dividerColor);
            int y = 0;

            //go through each field, figure it's height, and draw a line under it
            for(int i=0;i<getFieldCount();i++) {
                if(i != getFieldCount() - 1) {
                    int height = getField(i).getHeight();
                    y += height;

                    graphics.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y);
                }
            }
        }

        graphics.setColor(oldColor);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only methods available to draw four round corners you can use a clipping rectangle to clip the drawing at a straight line, i.e. you actually paint a larger rounded rect but clip the lower (or upper) part of it.